# Application Halt for few second on some client's systems

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, user-interface, sql-server-2014

i have a chat application which is perfectly working on debug mode and also running smoothly on client's machines but from last 2 days it's UI get stuck/halt for 10-30 seconds after that it start running again, this process of halt and running happen continuously. its happening only on few machines. i don't know where to start. All users are sitting on same floor so that's not an internet issue neither a system memory issue. If you guys think its a memory issue let me know what to check then?

Comment: You tag it with SQL server. Are you blocking UI during querying? Then that could be SQL related issue. What makes you think it's a memory? Is application runs continuously for over 2 days??

Comment: Do you not have any idea at all which calls it is that's taking time? Not even if it's in the web app, some SQL query(ies) or even if it's on the client or server?

Comment: There are 4-5 web services calls on the interface where applications start halting. All those calls are asynchronous so that what bothering me why UI got halt. Those Web service call fetching and saving data to sql server, that's why i tag sql server. This issue is happening on few machines that's why i think it's might be memory related issue. There are 50 machines on the floor and application is running fine on 40 machine. this halting issue is happening only 10 machines that why i was thinking this issue is related to those 10 machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was due to internet, The machines where software was halting are on different internet which is little slow so that's is why this issue is occurring.